# What is the best way to identify a bike part and how to get that information?

Tags: shopping

it seems the bike industry does not have a common standard or maybe I missed it.

If I want to get a list of all bike parts a manufacturer offers, how would I go about that? Is there [EAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number) I could search and access somehow? Or are the manufacturer part ids somewhere available?

My friends with bike shops all use manual processes, that seems a little cumbersome.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ins and outs to this question.

Since your question is about **all** parts a manufacturer offers, the short answer is no, there's nothing close to what you're asking about. The reason is that at some level, many brands and manufacturers offer service parts and other minor items that simply are not all listed neatly anywhere in the public sphere. These are available to dealers, and in some cases to consumers depending on what policy/strategy the company employs with working with consumers directly. Many of these will have EAN/UPC codes, and it's increasingly common they all will for a given brand, but some don't.

Also since this question is about all parts for any manufacturer, it bears pointing out that some types of products that are sold or exist in highly configurable formats may not get an EAN/UPC for all or any of the permutations. Some rims and high-end hubs are like this, for example. In other words, it's fairly common that a company selling a high end hub that you can buy in any of X colors, Y drillings, and Z FHB types isn't going to have XYZ EAN/UPC codes for it; they may or may not have them for the most common permutations.

There used to be a company called Bike-alog that was a subscription database service for bike shops that aimed to do something pretty close to what you're describing. Its bigger role was tracking which distributor carried what, and it could check stock for some distributors in real time, which given the technology of the time was a major time-saver. I believe it was for the US market only. It went out of business sometime in the early 2010's, and I believe (not completely sure) the major reason was that bike industry POS systems, which are all also subscription services, were reaching maturity around that time in their ability to do the same research/ordering functions but in a way that had a lot of other integrated features for businesses, so Bikealog became something of an extraneous expense for users. To an extent or in some cases, industry POS systems can be used to do some of what you're asking about for a shop or business, since they do aggregate what each distributor carries in a searchable format, but it's not exactly the same thing because you don't know that you're looking at a list of everything a company makes, and you typically won't be, nor will the distinction typically be clear what's currently in production, out of production but still available, etc.

The bigger companies (Shimano is a major example) tend to have all sorts of parts that are only marketed in certain countries. This is common enough that in many cases, getting to a real and true unified, accurate list of everything a given company puts out in the world is  a major project no matter who you are.

Looking narrower than the question of how to find every part made by every brand, there are any number of individual examples of how to figure out all the primary offerings (i.e. everything besides the more obscure stuff as above) for a given brand, especially if the goal was to figure out everything in current production. One example is that whenever a brand has an exclusive distributorship deal with a distributor in a sufficiently big market, there's a decent chance that distributor is going to be carrying 100% of their current offerings, and in some cases distributor catalogs are browsable in priceless or MSRP-only format by the public. Another thing to understand is that these days, so many companies are running their own DTC operations that there is often no difference between what's available for sale on the DTC site versus the entirety of what's out there; distributors are in many cases getting filled from the same facility as the DTC.